# MVC pattern in java, more than one update method in observer

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I'm writing a chess game with gui in mvc design.

Step 1: a main menu pops and you choose a game mod.

Step 2: once you chose, the main menu closes and a new window opens with the board and pieces, then you play with the mouse.

**for step 1**; I use actionEvent and check the string of the button you clicked on.
for example, you have the button Standard Game, and then model sets up the dataBoard and notifies observer(=view).

**for step 2**; I use mouseEvent and check relative coordinates x/y, the model does what it does and decides if you can move the piece.

I want to have two update methods in view, one for `step 1`, the other for `step 2`.
currently it always goes to the first update.

```
// this is in the model, initializing once you chose a game mod,
// this is for the first step.
public void initializeGame(String givenString){
    abstractGame = factoryGame.createGame(givenString);
    abstractGame.startPlaying(boardTest);
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers(5);
}

// this is in the model, doing stuff, this is for the second step.
public boolean checkGivenCoordinates(int sourceRow, int sourceColumn, int     destinationRow, int destinationColumn) throws IncorrectCoordinatesException,     IncorrectColorException, InvalidMoveException
{
    if(abstractGame.checkCorrectCoordinates(sourceRow, sourceColumn, destinationRow, destinationColumn) == true)
    {
        abstractGame.checkMove(sourceRow, sourceColumn, destinationRow, destinationColumn);
        int [] changeView = {sourceRow, sourceColumn, destinationRow, destinationColumn};
        System.out.println("Model     : in the move ");
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(changeView);
        return true;
    }
    else
        throw new IncorrectCoordinatesException();
}


// Called from the Model
public void update(Observable obs, Object obj) { // this is the one it always goes to now.

    //who called us and what did they send?
    System.out.println ("First update View    : Observable is " + obs.getClass() + ", object passed is " + obj.getClass());
} //update()

// Called from the Model
/* this is for step 2, but is not invoked.
   The array I send holds 4 ints, source row/column and destination row/column.
   this is what I do in model just prior to notifying,
   supposed to go to step 2's update method,
   but as stated, it doesnt.
*/
public void update(Observable obs, int[] obj) {

    //who called us and what did they send?
    System.out.println ("Second update View     : Observable is " + obs.getClass() + ", object passed is " + obj.getClass());
    graphBoardView.setMove(obj[0], obj[1], obj[2], obj[3]);

} //update()
```

so,

1) can I have more than one update in a single class?

2) if so, how can I direct notifying to the correct update method?

3) if q1 isn't possible, how can I bypass this?

4) could it be that Object obj causes it to always go to the first one?

thanks in advance,
ariel.

Comment: this line: notifyObservers(5); is a remainder of past version, but since it too goes to the first view im clueless, because it could have been considered as an int array too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed have more than one method of the same name, but with different parameters, in the same class.

You can see what you're seeing when the compiler cant determine which method to use if there is ambiguity - remember that that an array is an `Object` too.

With a simple test case it should work:

```
new Test().update(new Observable(), new int[]{1, 2});
new Test().update(new Observable(), new Object());
```

The correct methods get invoked.

How are you calling your methods?

Comment: where do i need to write this check?

Comment: Sorry - I was suggesting that perhaps you provide an example of how you're calling these methods, as I have above.  If its exactly the same it should work as expected

Comment: for example if you somehow invoked the method like this "new Test().update(new Observable(), (Object)new int[]{1, 2});" then the first method would be called, despite the fact you're actually passing in an int array

Comment: why would i do that? i simply setChanged() and notifyObservers().

maybe i miss something here, but why do i need to do that if thats automatic?

Comment: Aaah, I understand - I'd missed something in this before.  I assume you're using the Observer interface for this?  If so there is only 1 method in that interface and therefore its the only one that will get call for updates.  Does this make sense?

Comment: Observer.update(Observable o, Object arg) - this is the only method on Observer - your class may add another, but the mechanism you're using will only see whats available on the Observer interface

Comment: so basically i have to write an ugly switch-case, instanceof and that.

bummer, thanks for the help!

Comment: another question, i decided to direct from the update to updateX where X denotes something i know, do i need to send there the Observable as well as the obj?
what is the observable importance out of the update?

Comment: If I understand your question, the Observable is the thing to be updated and obj is the parameter - i'd imagine you'd need both, but it really does depend on your use case I'm afraid - hope that helps!

Comment: Yeah, that looks fine - its not ideal, but given your situation its probably the best you can do :-)

Comment: done with graphics, all that is left now is the other game mods and check(+mate).
thanks alot for your help, ill send ya it in the end if you want :P

Comment: an update: done with check and check status. things to do: checkmate(which wont be hard, we only need to check if the *king* cannot save himself) and other games mods, pawn reaching last row.

Comment: ofc not, its too large for that, i can send it to you via email.

Comment: great - try seanlandsman@hotmail.com - I look forward to seeing it!